# Removing a particular category from a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a single column in a data frame in R that looks something like this:

```
blue
green
blue
yellow
black
blue
green
```

How do I remove all the rows that indicate **blue**? Please keep in mind that I don't want a NULL value represented in that row: I want the entire row removed.

Thank you :)

Comment: could you give us dput(head(dframe,n=5))? I know it's terribly verbose, but do so anyway. commenting "you still have trouble" without any other information makes it impossible to help you out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also be careful about the difference between a *factor variable* and *character vector*.

Factors retain all original levels by default unless you reassign the altered vector as a new factor, or use one of the relevel functions.

```
> DF <- data.frame(v = factor(c("red", "blue", "green", "blue")))
> summary(DF)
     v    
 blue :2  
 green:1  
 red  :1  
> summary(DF[ DF$v != "blue", , drop=FALSE])
     v    
 blue :0  
 green:1  
 red  :1  
> DF <- DF[ DF$v != "blue", , drop=FALSE]; DF$v <- factor(DF$v); summary(DF)
     v    
 green:1  
 red  :1  
>
```

Comment: If you don't want that behaviour, you shouldn't be using a factor.

Comment: I'm of no particular opinion here: I like factors. I am merely providing assistance to what appears to be a new user -- as those are most likely to fall into the trap provided by R's default value of `stringsAsFavtors`.

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
> df1 = data.frame(a=c("Red", "Blue", "Red"), b=1:3)
> df1[df1$a!= "Blue",]
    a b
1 Red 1
3 Red 3
```

Comment: Thanks csgillespie. But unfortunately still having trouble. This is what I have entered:datafr[datafr$"FOCUS.APP"!= "ScreenSaverEngine",] datafr is my data frame; FOCUS.APP is the name of the column; ScreenSaverEngine is the name of the rows I want to eliminate.

Comment: @Eric : You have to remove the "" around FOCUS.APP. Please be a bit more punctual in copying code, you seem to make those errors regularly. Did you go through the R guide of Owen and the introduction to R already?

Comment: @Joris: I've tried a test case with "" around FOCUS.APP and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

If all those square brackets and commas and dollar signs confuse you, then why not try 'subset':

```
> d=data.frame(a=c("Red", "Blue", "Red"), b=1:3)
> subset(d,a!="Blue")
    a b
1 Red 1
3 Red 3
```

Comment: Does subset refactor the variable to get rid of empty levels or do the empty levels remain. What would have happened if one had entered table(a) afterwards?

Comment: As Farrel suggests, this doesn't actually remove the empty level.

Answer (score -1):

```
> Data[Data!="blue"]
[1] "green"  "yellow" "black"  "green"
```

or

```
> Data[which(Data!="blue",TRUE)]
[1] "green"  "yellow" "black"  "green"
```

Edit to respond to Joris' comment (this works for 1-column data.frames):

```
> str(Data)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 4 levels "black","blue",..: 2 3 2 4 1 2 3
```

Comment: That's for a vector, doesn't work with a dataframe. Add a comma after "blue" and forget about the which() option, I can't think of a reason why one would use an extra function if there is absolutely no need for it.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I'm assuming Data is the name of the data frame, correct? I tried this out, but all it does is print out my data frame. Here is what I inputted: datafr[which(datafr!="ScreenSaverEngine",TRUE)] I've replaced Data with the name of my data frame which is 'datafr'

Comment: Joris and Joshua... I'm still a bit confused. I've added the comma like this: datafr[datafr!="ScreenSaverEngine,"]. datafr is my dataframe and ScreenSaverEngine are the rows I want to get rid of.

Comment: @Eric : see the answer of csgillespie. You have to put the comma behind the quotation mark, not before.

Comment: @Joris: it works if the data.frame only has one column.  I assumed "single column in a data frame" meant the data.frame only had one column.

Comment: @Eric: That comma behind the " will tell R that you're interested in rows. If you have a data.frame and only one element within [], R will think you're interested in columns. [, x] is equivalent to the latter statement.